# Creating a Google Sheets extension using Python

Tags: python, google-api, google-api-python-client, google-search-console, google-workspace-add-ons

I am pretty new to Python, and I recently took on a project in which I am supposed to create a google sheets add on in python that edits that specific sheet when it is used.

https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/guides/alternate-runtimes

I stumbled upon this tutorial, but I am very lost. I do not understand what "Pick your hosting infrastructure and set up your HTTPS endpoints" means, and I was able to follow steps 1-8 under "Create a Deployment Resource", but I was lost on step 9.

Could somebody help me with this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Picking your hosting infrastructure is saying to basically pick your server provider. Hosting just refers to servers because everything on the web needs to be hosted for everyone to access. HTTPS endpoints are urls that points to the location of resources in the server.

Step 9 was referring to creating a json file with information about your add on. I'm not particularly comfortable with JSON but from my understanding it's just using attribute:value pairs like CSS but it's used for storing and transmitting  information.

Really hopes this helps, don't give up and dont get intimidated by this terminology. Best of luck!